# Numpy array not reshaping

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to process some image data in numpy, and i need the array to have a certain shape. The input i get is of shape `(28,28)` and i run `imgData.reshape((1,28,28,1))`. However when checking in debugger(and asserting) the shape still reports as `(28,28)` as if nothing has changed

The code below:

```
@app.route("/image", methods=["POST"])
def recognize():
    r = request
    filestr = request.files['image'].read()
    # convert string data to numpy array
    npimg = np.fromstring(filestr, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(npimg, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    imgData = img.astype(np.float32) / 255
    imgData.reshape((1, 28, 28, 1))
    pred = imgr.guess(imgData)
    return Response(pred, 200)
```

Can anyone spot what i am doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work in-place. Assign the result back to a name. `imgData = imgData.reshape((1, 28, 28, 1))`.

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) before asking questions.

Comment: I now realize my mistake. Thank you for noticing

Answer (score 0):

you have assign the result of reshape to a variable.

```
reshaped_array = imgData.reshape((1, 28, 28, 1))
print(reshaped_array.shape)
```